# creating queries in excel using VB and macros

Tags: sql, excel, vba, insert

I have a lot of data in excel with different columns. My task is to create insert statement for each row. I have done using concatenate function of excel but I want to automate this method. The other task is to replace ' (single quotes) with ''(2 single quotes) so that characters can be adjusted in the sql statement. The main is once I get the excel, I run my script which will automatically make all the queries. And after that, I will run those queries manually in SQL developer or TOAD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any information about your table and your Excel data, here's an example supposing that your excel data is in columns `A:D` starting from row 2, with the same layout as your table. I also suppose that all your fields are text type.

```
Sub createQueries()

    Dim r As Range, cel As Range, record As String

    'Get the range to export
    With Sheet1
        Set r = .Range("A2:D" & .Range("D999999").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With

    ' Create a text file for the query
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile("c:\SO\queries.txt")
        For Each r In r.Rows
            ' create an Insert line into the query
            record = "INSERT INTO MYTABLE (""FieldA"", ""FieldB"", ""FieldC"", ""FieldD"") Values ("
            For Each cel In r.Cells
                record = record & "'" & Replace(cel.Text, "'", "''") & "',"
            Next
            record = Left(record, Len(record) - 1) & ");"
            .WriteLine record
        Next
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```